# Variable named interface

Tags: java, naming-conventions, xtext

I need a variable that represents an interface. I was wondering if there is a "standard" name for such a variable, like for example the clazz for a Class variable. I was thinking of naming it aInterface, but I don't realy like this name...

Comment: what do u mean by that _clazz_? like `Class clazz = yourObj.getClass()` ???

Comment: what's the type of the variable?

Comment: @Uko: yes that's what I mean.

Comment: @Liviu: Well it's a bit more complicated. I'm using Xtext for some code generation and the variable just models a generated interface.

Comment: @Uko: Here `clazz` is just a name of the variable of type `java.lang.Class`. In general, although it is a bad practice people tend to use `String string` for declaring a `String` variable quickly. The same way `clazz` is used as we cannot use `class` which is a restricted key word in Java. This is generally used when one tries to load classes programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general my interface names start with I, like, `IMyInterface`. And I use 'i' as prefix for variable name where I need to indicate the variable is interface, like `iMyInterfaceVar`. But no such restriction or standard rule.

Just for sake of completeness, here is [The Java Code Convention Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Answer (score 6):

In the lines of `clazz`, you could use `interfaze`!

Comment: Funny, but I hope Deelazee doesn't take this too seriously.